# Reusing image data URI multiple times in the same SVG document

Tags: svg

I'm using the same image multiple times in a single SVG document. Embedding the same image multiple times as a data uri using `xlink:href` seems like unnecessary file bloat.

What I currently have is: `<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64..."` appearing multiple times with the same data uri.

Is there a way to embed a data uri in a separate svg element and then link all the `image` elements to it, thus avoiding the data duplication?

Comment: @RobertLongson That was the solution, thank you. You should post this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the image in a symbol and then point `<use>` elements at the symbol.